# Is Pink Panther Theme ALL in Em key?

Tags: theory, harmony

referring to [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/89899/functional-analysis-of-the-pink-panther) question, it was determined that Pink Panther theme is actually in Em, but I was wondering if the key could be considered Em even when the theme varies (Consider [this](https://youtu.be/lp6z3s1Gig0?t=42) video from minute 0:42 onwards), because I tried to improvise some pentatonic Em scales on and it seems there's just something wrong...
Could someone explain me why this is happening?

Comment: Suggest you use this as an example, but ask specifically about the modulation, otherwise 'vtc looms!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this question will stand, as it's asking specifics about one song. However, it appears it's modulated into Gm. The redeeming factor *may* be your last sentence. It sounds like a smooth transition as Em to G is the relative minor to major, then it's morphed into the *parallel* key, as in from G major to G minor.